# How to configure PostgreSQL ODBC Driver

Tags: postgresql, docker, odbc, cratedb

I have a database on Crate DB. The database program is started through `docker-compose.yml` file. It is running on http://192.168.99.100:4200 (this is the docker machine's IP with the Crate's port)

I want to connect the Crate DB with Power BI. When I try to configure the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver, I don't know what to type on "Server" field.

So far I've tried "`localhost`", "`127.0.0.1`","`0.0.0.0`", "`192.168.99.100`" but none of these works.

So my question is, which IP address should I type on the "server" field?

[image: connectionError]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup seems correct. Make sure the port `5432` is correctly published. Assuming you're using the official [cratedb image](https://hub.docker.com/_/crate), the exposed ports in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/crate/docker-crate/blob/master/Dockerfile) used to assemble the image are the following:

```
# http: 4200 tcp
# transport: 4300 tcp
# postgres protocol ports: 5432 tcp
EXPOSE 4200 4300 5432
```

Therefore, in order to access those services remotely you have to publish their corresponding ports. In `docker-compose.yml` configure the port mappings if you haven't already done so:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  cratedb:
    image: crate
    ports:
       - 5432:5432
       - 4200:4200
       - 4300:4300
```

More about port mappings in the *ports section* of the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/). Now you should be able to connect using the `ODBC PostgreSql` driver to the IP address of the host (i.e. `192.168.99.100`) and port `5432`.

In alternative you could run the container with port bindings:

```
 docker run -d  -p 4200:4200 -p 5432:5432 -p 4300:4300 crate
```

If you still can connect to the database, check the firewall settings.